# OpenCL transpose kernel how is get_local_id being used

Tags: c, matrix, opencl

Code taken from a sample. I created a project with it and it works, but I don't understand some parts.

For the sake of the example, say I have a 32x32 matrix, there are 36 work items and so get_global_id(0) goes from 0 -> 35 I presume, and size = MATRIX_DIM/4 = 8.

```
__kernel void transpose(__global float4 *g_mat,
   __local float4 *l_mat, uint size) {

   __global float4 *src, *dst;

   /* Determine row and column location */
   int col = get_global_id(0);
   int row = 0;
   while(col >= size) {
      col -= size--;
      row++;
   }
   col += row;
   size += row;

   /* Read source block into local memory */
   src = g_mat + row * size * 4 + col;
   l_mat += get_local_id(0)*8;
```

In the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` call, the arg `local_work_size` was set to `NULL` which according to the manual means let the compiler or something figure it out:

`local_work_size can also be a NULL value in which case the OpenCL implementation will determine how to be break the global work-items into appropriate work-group instances.`

But I don't understand the multiply by 8, which gives an address offset into local memory for the work group I suppose. Can someone please explain this?

```
   l_mat[0] = src[0];
   l_mat[1] = src[size];
   l_mat[2] = src[2*size];
   l_mat[3] = src[3*size];

   /* Process block on diagonal */
   if(row == col) {
      src[0] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].x, l_mat[1].x, l_mat[2].x, l_mat[3].x);
      src[size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].y, l_mat[1].y, l_mat[2].y, l_mat[3].y);
      src[2*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].z, l_mat[1].z, l_mat[2].z, l_mat[3].z);
      src[3*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].w, l_mat[1].w, l_mat[2].w, l_mat[3].w);
   }
   /* Process block off diagonal */
   else {
      /* Read destination block into local memory */
      dst = g_mat + col * size * 4 + row;
      l_mat[4] = dst[0];
      l_mat[5] = dst[size];
      l_mat[6] = dst[2*size];
      l_mat[7] = dst[3*size];

      /* Set elements of destination block */
      dst[0] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].x, l_mat[1].x, l_mat[2].x, l_mat[3].x);
      dst[size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].y, l_mat[1].y, l_mat[2].y, l_mat[3].y);
      dst[2*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].z, l_mat[1].z, l_mat[2].z, l_mat[3].z);
      dst[3*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[0].w, l_mat[1].w, l_mat[2].w, l_mat[3].w);

      /* Set elements of source block */
      src[0] =
         (float4)(l_mat[4].x, l_mat[5].x, l_mat[6].x, l_mat[7].x);
      src[size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[4].y, l_mat[5].y, l_mat[6].y, l_mat[7].y);
      src[2*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[4].z, l_mat[5].z, l_mat[6].z, l_mat[7].z);
      src[3*size] =
         (float4)(l_mat[4].w, l_mat[5].w, l_mat[6].w, l_mat[7].w);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l_mat` is being used a a local store for threads in a work-group.  Specifically, it is being used because accesses to local memory are orders of magnitude faster than to global memory.

Each thread needs 8 `float4`s.  Doing the following pointer arithmetic

```
l_mat += get_local_id(0)*8;
```

moves the `l_mat` pointer for each thread so that it doesn't overlap with other threads' data.

This *could* cause an error since the local_size wasn't specified and we are unable to ensure that the size of `l_mat` is sufficient to store the values for each thread.

Comment: "Each thread needs 8 float4s" You mean how it goes l_mat[0] --> l_mat[7] when reading in to local memory right? That makes sense... But I thought each `float4` is 16 bytes, and our memory is byte addressable - Wait a second, l_mat is declared as a pointer to float4s, so I guess the alignment is taken care of. Well, if that's what's going on I understand, but it's some tricky stuff!

Comment: @YoungMoney: there is no alignment issue here, this is just usual C pointers arithmetic which make complete abstraction of the underlying element size in bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

**l_mat** is used as a temporary buffer for storing the two matrix components to invert for all the work-items.

So for each work-item it needs to store **2 * 4** float4s, hence : **offset = get_local_id(0)*2*4 = get_local_id(0)*8**.